# mPDF not adding header/footer on new pages

Tags: php, mpdf

Essentially, the headers and footers are only displaying on the first page and the first page after I manually break the page.

But header and footer are NOT being displayed on any additional pages that are a natural continuation due to long HTML content. (i.e. where there is no manual )

```
<htmlpageheader name="header">Page Hader</htmlpageheader>
<htmlpagefooter name="footer"><p>Copyright <b>blablabla</b> 1999 - <?php echo date('Y') ?></p></htmlpagefooter>
```

Header+footer will display on this page

```
<sethtmlpageheader name="header" page="all" value="on" show-this-page="1" />
<sethtmlpagefooter name="footer" page="all" value="on" />


<p>(PDF cover)</p>
<h1>Report</h1>
```

Header+footer will display on the first page but not on subsequent pages

```
<pagebreak />
<sethtmlpageheader name="header" page="all" value="on" show-this-page="1" />
<sethtmlpagefooter name="footer" page="all" value="on" />
LONG HTML CONTENT
THAT EXCEEDS PAGE SIZE
```

Comment: @page did not solved my problem. so after alot searches I found the solution for the problem. And here I answered you the way.

Answer (score 10):

You can add @page like this:

```
@page {
 header: header_name;
 footer: footer_name;
}
```

[Using @page](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html)

[Headers & Footers](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-footers.html)

I hope that is useful

Comment: Just to make it clear: you don't have to add these to the css, but if for any other reason you use @page (e.g. margins, padding....), then it is mandatory to put the header and footer info there.

Answer (score 6):

If you use @page in styles, Removing @page resolved the problem.  That was what I had, and what worked for me.

Comment: See Giovani Generali answer if you're using @page because it's correct one for that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am providing you a code snippet which solves the problem.

```
<?php

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->useOddEven = 1;    // Use different Odd/Even headers and footers and mirror margins

// Define the Headers before writing anything so they appear on the first page

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">My document</div>','O');

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">My document</div>','E');

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('

<table width="100%" style="vertical-align: bottom; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"><tr>

<td width="33%"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">{DATE j-m-Y}</span></td>

<td width="33%" align="center" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>

<td width="33%" style="text-align: right; ">My document</td>

</tr></table>

');  // Note that the second parameter is optional : default = 'O' for ODD

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('

<table width="100%" style="vertical-align: bottom; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"><tr>

<td width="33%"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">My document</span></td>

<td width="33%" align="center" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>

<td width="33%" style="text-align: right; ">{DATE j-m-Y}</td>

</tr></table>

', 'E');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hallo World');

$mpdf->Output();
```

Refer to this link for more info.[MPDF Headers and Footers](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-2.html)