# Is there a way to hide a footer in a pdf file created with MPDF?

Tags: mpdf

I have created a pdf file with MPDF in PHP. When i insert the header and footers in it, they automatically gets displayed on all the pages of the pdf file. But i want to stop these header and footer from getting displayed on the first page and display them starting from the second page of the pdf file. I have searched the net but unable to find a solution.

Comment: Try finding an inspiration on these SO questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670208/mpdf-different-header-for-first-page
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379725/how-to-remove-header-footer-only-for-the-first-page-mpdf
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396251/mpdf-header-for-first-page-only-but-footer-for-every-page
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078850/mpdf-not-adding-header-footer-on-new-pages

Comment: One more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019643/mpdf-disable-page-number-header-and-footer-on-first-page